# Django class-based view processing form and adjusting context accordingly

Tags: python, django

I'm pretty new to Django and Python in general. I am building a Django app at the moment and am trying to stick to class-based views.

I have a form (FormView) that I would like process, meaning take the data, clean it up and store it in the database. When processed I'd simply like to show the form again (so no redirect to another success page) and show the result of the processing above the form. How would I do that? I have played around with get_context_data to add the additional context for the result message but can't figure out how and where to process the data and how to tie it together with updating the context data then. Any help would be appreciated.

forms.py:

```py
from django import forms

class URLsForm(forms.Form):
    list_of_urls = forms.CharField(label='One URL per line', widget=forms.Textarea)
```

views.py

```py
from django.views.generic import FormView
from .models import URL
from .forms import URLsForm

class URLBatchCreateView(FormView):
    form_class = URLsForm
    template_name = 'bot/url_batch_create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('url_batch_create')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super(URLBatchCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['created_urls'] = 'The result'
            return context
```

url_batch_create.html:

```html
{% extends 'bot/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% if created_urls %}
    <div>The following URLs where created:<br>{{ created_urls }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="" method ="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py:

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import URLBatchCreateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('url/batchcreate', URLBatchCreateView.as_view(), name='url_batch_create'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have played around with get_context_data to add the additional context for the result message

Yes, get_context_data is good for passing the data to the template.

> but can't figure out how and where to process the data

You were on the right track with this too.  It could be done in the form_valid.

> and how to tie it together with updating the context data then.

For this you'll need to have a reference to the database object where the data was stored to.  Your current approach redirects to the same page without any parameters.  That won't work, because when the browser is loading the page from the redirected URL it's another request and if you don't have a reference to the created object, there is no way to find which one was created.

You might want to take a look at the CreateView and UpdateView which might provide a more elegant solution (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/) but I'll provide an example how to complete your current approach.

You didn't specify how the data is stored so I'll provide an example of models.py so that my other changes make sense:

```
from django.db import models

class URLSet(models.Model):
    pass

class URL(models.Model):
    urlset = models.ForeignKey(URLSet, related_name="urls",
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    url = models.URLField()
```

The URLBatchCreateView could also handle the edits, so I renamed it to URLBatchCreateEditView.  It should be able to get a reference to the created URLSet object, i.e. its id.  Then we can work on based on that:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic import FormView

from .forms import URLsForm
from .models import URL, URLSet


class URLBatchCreateEditView(FormView):
    form_class = URLsForm
    template_name = 'bot/url_batch_create.html'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.urlset = None

    def get(self, request, *args, urlset_id=None, **kwargs):
        if urlset_id:
            self.urlset = get_object_or_404(URLSet, id=urlset_id)
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_initial(self):
        data = super().get_initial()
        if self.urlset:
            data.update({'list_of_urls': '\n'.join(self.get_urls())})
        return data

    def get_urls(self):
        if self.urlset is None:
            return None
        return [x.url for x in self.urlset.urls.all()]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        urls_text = form.cleaned_data['list_of_urls']
        if not self.urlset:
            self.urlset = URLSet.objects.create()
        else:
            self.urlset.urls.all().delete()
        for url in urls_text.splitlines():
            URL.objects.create(url=url, urlset=self.urlset)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('url_batch_edit', kwargs={'urlset_id': self.urlset.id})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['created_urls'] = self.get_urls()
        context['urlset'] = self.urlset
        return context
```

You'll need the new url too:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('url/batchcreate', URLBatchCreateEditView.as_view(),
         name='url_batch_create'),
    path('url/batchedit/<int:urlset_id>', URLBatchCreateEditView.as_view(),
         name='url_batch_edit'),
]
```

And maybe the button should't say "Create" when it's in edit mode:

```
{% if urlset %}
    <input type="submit" value="Save changes">
{% else %}
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
{% endif %}
```

Finally, it might be a good idea to add validation to the form:

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators


def validate_url_lines(value, schemes=('http', 'https')):
    validate_url = validators.URLValidator(schemes=schemes)
    for line in value.splitlines():
        validate_url(line)


class URLsForm(forms.Form):
    list_of_urls = forms.CharField(label='One URL per line',
                                   widget=forms.Textarea,
                                   validators=[validate_url_lines])
```

Comment: I totally missed the fact that there is a redirect at the end where the success page doesn't know anything about the data submitted. Interesting approach with using a separate model for URLSet. Will give this a try. Thanks a lot!